# How to rename all files in a directory by inserting a string at beginning of each file name?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I would like to create a batch script (a .txt or .exe - I do not have PowerShell) to rename a group of files. The current format of the filename is `file_name_51.zip` and I would like to rename this file to `MoreDetail_Detail_file_name_51.zip`.

I have tried to use a simple "Rename-Item" script or CMD but my computer does not recognize that code. I saw a good example of a possible code from dbenham:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd .
subst #: .
#:
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt^|findstr /er "_[0-9]*.txt"') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ("!name:_=\x!") do (
    endlocal
    set "file=%%F"
    set "name=%%~pA"
    set "num=%%~nA"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "num=0000!num:~1!"
    set "name=!name:~1,-1!"
    ren "!file!" "!name:\x=_!!num:~-5!.txt"
    endlocal
  )
)
popd
subst /d #:
```

But I am a novice and I don't know how to manipulate that to do what I need. Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b a-d ') do if /i not "%%~nxa"=="%~nx0" ren "%%a" "MoreDetail_Detail_%%~nxa"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I attempted to create a .bat from this and got a "file not found" error. Is there a way around that?

Comment: The batch file expects your files to be in the same directory that the batch file is in.  There was a problem where the batch file will be renamed too so I edited the code above.